# Insert additional attributes in instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, instance-variables

Can somebody help me to insert in my instance an attribute with always the same value?

**Actual:**

```
#<Test surname: "example", givename: "test">
```

**Target:**

```
#<Test surname: "example", givename: "test", newvalue: "text">
```

How do I have to change this code?

```
@users.each do |user|
  user
end
```

Or can I implement this with something like `:attr_accessor`?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the same value for all instances of your class you can do following:

```
class Some
  def initialize
    @value = "Some value"
  end

  def newvalue
    @value
  end
end
```

this will give `newvalue` with "Some value" text for all instances of class Some or whatever you call it. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new column to your Model. For that you can use a migration. First create a migration like this:

```
rails g migration addNewValueToTests
```

Then you will find the migration file in `db/migrations/` there you add a `add_column` to the `self.up` method like this:

```
def self.up
     add_column :table_name, :column_name, :datatype #datatype like integer, sting, text,....
end
```

then you migrate the database with the `rake db:migrate` command and the column + setter/getter methods will be added to the model!

// If you just want an alias you can use `alias_attribute` in the model like this:

```
alias_attribute :new_name, :current_name
```